# Java Type Hints on Generic Method Calling

Tags: java, generics, types

I'm wondering what is the proper way to call a static method with a signature like this:

```
public static <T1, T2> Map<T1, Set<T2>> aggregate(List<Map<String, Object>> list, 
        String colK, String colV) {
    ...
}
```

I was tempted to call it like this for some reason:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = aggregate<String, Integer>(lData, "id", "ref");
```

but it didn't compile unless I changed it to:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = aggregate(lData, "id", "ref");
```

I'm just wondering why it didn't need the hints on the right hand side.  And instead gave me compilation error.  It says it expects a semi-colon after the hints on the right hand side.  Is the second one a proper way to call the method?  Could somebody shed some light please?

Comment: You attempted the C# syntax. In Java, the type parameters go before the method name. `SomeClass.<types>staticMethod()`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Oh!  That explains a lot!  lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html), the way to call the method would be:

```
ClassName.<String, Integer>aggregate(lData, "id", "ref");
```

where `ClassName` is the name of the class that the method is contained in.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the quick reply.  Now I remember I saw it before.  However, if I want to omit the class name, since it is being called within the same class, how would it be like?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot omit the class name in this case.