# How to typecast one List to another List in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have Cache declared as Map:

```
private Cache<String,Object> operatingParametersCache;
```

I am getting data from service class and I am putting into Cache:

```
List<OperatingParametersDTO> objList=this.operatingParamService.getOperatingParamDTO();

          operatingParametersCache = cacheManager
                .createCache("cacheOfOperatingService", CacheConfigurationBuilder
                        .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                String.class,Object.class,
                                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100000)).withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(60000,
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS))));

        operatingParametersCache.put("CACHE_OPERATING_PARAMETER",objList);
```

I tried to get the values from the Cache using:

```
 List<Object> operatingvalues = new ArrayList<>();
        operatingParametersCache.forEach(entry -> operatingvalues.add(entry.getValue()));
        System.out.println(operatingvalues);
```

I want to convert this  `List<Object>` to `List<OperatingParametersDTO>` ,so I tried to convert using :

```
List<OperatingParametersDTO> listA = new ArrayList<OperatingParametersDTO>(operatingvalues);
```

But I got : Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.List)'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve constructor for ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982845/cannot-resolve-constructor-for-arraylist)

Comment: @MebinJoe That is an entirely different problem than the problem of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to declare a list with proper type:

```
List<OperatingParametersDTO> operatingvalues = new ArrayList<>();
```

and cast:

```
operatingParametersCache.forEach(entry -> operatingvalues.addAll(((List) entry.getValue()).stream().map(el -> (OperatingParametersDTO) el).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

You can also cast every single element:

```
List<OperatingParametersDTO> listA = operatingvalues.stream()
    .map(el -> (OperatingParametersDTO) el)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You cannot cast collection of one type to collection of other type, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763192/java-collections-covariance-problem).

Comment: i think it needs to be operatingParametersCache.stream() plz check ur code once..

Comment: You want to convert the list of `Object`s right? It's `operatingvalues` then.

Comment: my values are being stored as key,value in operatingParametersCache

Comment: but why did you put el -> (OperatingParametersDTO) el .. my datas are in operatingParametersCache object

Comment: In the third snipper you're gathering them in `operatingvalues` as `Object`s.

Comment: just see i have edited your code.But I am getting casting error

Comment: I tried your second appraoch but I got :add
(com.component.operatingparameters.entity.OperatingParametersDTO)
in List cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.Object)

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Its showing me in red marker that :add (com.component.operatingparameters.entity.OperatingParametersDTO) in List cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object) –

Comment: I tried to put inside the bracket and I got: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.tms.component.operatingparameters.entity.OperatingParametersDTO

Comment: so `entry.getValue()` is a list?

Comment: yes its List<Object>=entry.getValue(). So,I m stuck here. :(

Comment: @AshwinKarki then you need to combine both my solutions - check out my edit

Comment: thnk u for the effort :)

Comment: Instead of putting private Cache<String,Object> operatingParametersCache; can I put   Cache<String,List<OperatingParametersDTO>> operatingParametersCache;

Comment: That's also true:) I'm glad I could help;>

Comment: but for .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                String.class,Object.class ,I need to initialize String.class,List.class but it is not giving me.How to declare List in this line of code?

Comment: `List<OperatingParametersDTO>.class`

Comment: Cannot select from parameterized type in red marker When I did List<OperatingParametersDTO>.class

Comment: Then it has to be `List.class` and you need to cast.

Comment: i did (OperatingParametersDTO)List.class but it is showing me:inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Class<java.util.List>' to 'com.tms.component.operatingparameters.entity.OperatingParametersDTO

Comment: You cannot convert list to object, you would have to stay by casting elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FlatMap` here:

```
// Dummy Values (I have created 2 fields id and name)
List<OperatingParametersDTO> objList = new ArrayList<>();
objList.add(new OperatingParametersDTO(1, "ABC"));
objList.add(new OperatingParametersDTO(2, "DEF"));
objList.add(new OperatingParametersDTO(3, "GHI"));

// Adding List to Map
Map<String, Object> operatingParametersCache = new HashMap<>();
operatingParametersCache.put("CACHE_OPERATING_PARAMETER", objList);

// Converting List<Object> to List<OperatingParametersDTO> and printing
List<OperatingParametersDTO> listA  = operatingParametersCache.values().stream().map(e -> (List<OperatingParametersDTO>) e).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(listA);
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [OperatingParametersDTO{id=1, name='ABC'}, OperatingParametersDTO{id=2, name='DEF'}, OperatingParametersDTO{id=3, name='GHI'}]
> ```